# Passing Navigation from a functional component to a class compoent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component where i show the diffrent components i have called SearchScreen.js
i want to pass the navigation prop to the class component classed SearchList i tried the code bellow but i still get an undefined error for some reason  :

SearchScreen.js :

```
<SearchList navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

SearchList.js :

```
   <TouchableScale
                activeScale={0.9}
                tension={50}
                friction={7}
                useNativeDriver
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", {
                    data: item,
                  })
                }
              >
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error come from? Any stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional components you dont need `this` to access props.

So try in SearchScreen like this:

```js
<SearchList navigation={props.navigation} />
```

Be sure that this component has access to navigation

Comment: Infact in functional component you can't use this at all.